# Directional light and finding relevant shadow casters

Tags: directx11, shadows, shadow-mapping

Right now when culling the models to render for the directional light shadow map pass I just do a view frustrum culling using the main camera. At some angles, the objects will be outside the view but still obviously should cast shadows.

My question is, how do you cull/gather all the relevant shadow casters for a directional light?

Answer (score 3):

There is an advanced technology based on compute shaders that will analyze the depth buffer of the main camera, and return the min depth, and max depth, with 1 pixel precision (reduce operation). This information can be used to create a very precise frustum for the shadow camera.
Elements outside the view that casts shadows are only in the frustum that goes from the viewed zone to the light. (oblique in the direction of the lighting).

[image: shadow volume]

One issue with this is that you don't know the min/max before rendering the world, and you need the shadow map to render the world. So to palliate to that, you can simply use a min/max pair  that is one frame late. And to mitigate potential little artefacts if the player moves too fast, you can inflate the volume slightly by some epsilon.

Comment: I am using depth reduction through SDSM already, so I have the min/max depth. What I dont understand is, what do you use to test if the models are casting shadows or not?

Comment: Your question is puzzling in the sense that you should naturally think that every existing solid casts shadow, end of story. therefore your rendering volume (==the shadow camera view matrix), should incorporate everything, which is on its coarsest, the whole scene. For quality (and performance as a bonus), it is best to shrink the volume like schematized above. You won't be missing casters FOR SURE because you shrink orthogonaly to the light direction.

Comment: @KaiserJohaan My guess is you are having fears of losing casters because you think of shrinking the volume longitudinally (in the direction of the light). This is something you are indeed not allowed to do, or you risk (and will), lose shadow casters. That is why the schema says "found from scene AABB". This tells you that the extreme global world limit is used, and it does not depend on view. Which is how you ensure all potential casters will be included.

Comment: The shadow cam frustrum is an orthogonal projection matrix that is then rotated towards the light direction? If so how do you create such a matrix? And what would the shadow cam far plane be?

Comment: Also if that is the same camera used when rendering the shadow map, wouldn't it possibly loose alot of resolution, if the near plane is scene aabb and there might alot of empty space between the near plane and the first object?

Comment: you're right. you can optimize by taking a near plane that is only as near as necessary to get the first object in the semi-infinite reduced frustum :) Otherwise, scene box will still work, the resolution would be lost in the depth encoding indeed. There is a technique to mitigate this, which you probably know as "quantification". You can choose a custom "encoding" format of the depth. float, int32, linear, log...

Comment: To answer the question of where is the far plane, it is like drawn on the schema, the farthest corner of the volume created by the 2 frustums. (far with respect to light pos). Now lastly, to construct the view matrix you can use some helper functions. `D3DXMatrixOrthoLH` for perspective; and `D3DXMatrixLookAtLH` for the view (which would set the rotation). These functions don't exist anymore in DX11 but the source code has been opened, so just google and copy :)

Comment: I still don't quite get how the shadowcam frustrum is constructed. OK, you got the depth min/max for example.. how are they used in D3DXMatrixOrthoLH?

Answer (score 1):

I don't do a frustum cull with the main camera, but the shadow camera alone.

I calculate the AABB (axis aligned bounding box) of the shadow camera, then do the culling with that. A directional shadow camera is a box in itself (orthographic projection matrix projects to a side of the box). After the box is rotated (for different light direction), the AABB can still be computed easily (but it will be a little bigger than originally, so it is a bit wasteful).

I compute it like this: Rotate every corner of the bounding box, then find the new min and max corner from the bunch of new coordinates. An AABB is essentially just a pair of min and max points.

You can check AABB-AABB intersections after that which should be quite fast.

Comment: How do you build your shadow camera? Do you build a frustrum from the main camera and use the min/max X/Y/Z and use that as input for an orthogonal matrix?

Comment: No, I have 3 shadow cameras with different sizes for different cascades, such as close, mid and far cascades. Each set up by hand with different size and distance from main camera, but with same resolution. The shadow cameras are placed on the ray shot from the main camera (the camera's lookAt vector).
I build a shadow camera box when creating its projection matrix.

Comment: "The shadow cameras are placed on the ray shot from the main camera (the camera's lookAt vector)" - can you explain this more? Isnt it like... get the center of cascades frustrum and offset it in the light direction? The question is... offset by how much?

Comment: I mean that I offset each shadow camera in front of the main camera (where it's facing) by a value. The bigger the shadow camera box, the further. So when each frustum is placed, I rotate them by the light direction around their own center.